# How to count row in every column based on threshold

Tags: r

I have the following data set:

```
dat <- structure(list(Probes = structure(1:6, .Label = c("1415670_at",
"1415671_at", "1415672_at", "1415673_at", "1415674_a_at", "1415675_at"
), class = "factor"), Genes = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L,
3L), .Label = c("Atp6v0d1", "Copg1", "Dpm2", "Golga7", "Psph",
"Trappc4"), class = "factor"), bCD.ID.LN = c(1.133, 1.068, 1.01,
0.943, 1.048, 1.053), bCD.ID.LV = c(1.049, 1.006, 0.883, 0.799,
0.96, 1.104), bCD.ID.SP = c(1.124, 1.234, 1.029, 1.064, 1.118,
1.057), bCD.IP.LV = c(1.013, 1.082, 1.061, 0.982, 1.191, 1.053
), bCD.IP.SP = c(0.986, 1.102, 1.085, 0.997, 1.141, 1.041)), .Names = c("Probes",
"Genes", "bCD.ID.LN", "bCD.ID.LV", "bCD.ID.SP", "bCD.IP.LV",
"bCD.IP.SP"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

It looks like this:

```
> dat

        Probes    Genes bCD.ID.LN bCD.ID.LV bCD.ID.SP bCD.IP.LV bCD.IP.SP
1   1415670_at    Copg1     1.133     1.049     1.124     1.013     0.986
2   1415671_at Atp6v0d1     1.068     1.006     1.234     1.082     1.102
3   1415672_at   Golga7     1.010     0.883     1.029     1.061     1.085
4   1415673_at     Psph     0.943     0.799     1.064     0.982     0.997
5 1415674_a_at  Trappc4     1.048     0.960     1.118     1.191     1.141
6   1415675_at     Dpm2     1.053     1.104     1.057     1.053     1.041
```

What I want tod for 3rd column onward count row where the value is > 1.1
So it the end it looks like this:

```
bCD.ID.LN 1
bCD.ID.LV 1
bCD.ID.SP 3
bCD.IP.LV 1
bCD.IP.SP 2
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try `colSums` on a logical matrix based on the numeric columns in the dataset.

```
Count <- colSums(dat[-(1:2)] > 1.1, na.rm=TRUE)
```

If we need it as a `data.frame`

```
d1 <- data.frame(Cnames = names(Count), Count=unname(Count))
```

---

If it is a large dataset, converting to a logical matrix may not be memory efficient, in that case, it would be better to loop using `vapply`

```
vapply(dat[-(1:2)], function(x) sum(x > 1.1, na.rm=TRUE), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks. That's great. BTW, how come I got all NA in my actual case?
This is my code: http://dpaste.com/11KYXZ5

Comment: @neversaint If you have NA values in the original dataset, those values will be still there when it is converted to logical matrix.  So, use `colSums(..., na.rm=TRUE)`. Updated the post.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another version, this time using dplyr

```
dat %>% 
select(-c(Probes, Genes)) %>% 
summarise_each (funs(sum((. > 1.1))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative version using lapply()

```
lapply(dat[-c(1:2)], function(x) length(which(x > 1.1)))
```

or this if you want it as a data.frame()

```
data.frame( lapply(dat[-c(1:2)], function(x) length(which(x > 1.1))))
```

Comment: Why post two separate answers? It is better to merge them into one.

Comment: I thought it better to keep base's lapply() separate from the dplyr ones. Hope that's OK.

Comment: Mostly not, giving two separate answers gives the impression that you are too eager to gain reputation points. Especially when the answers are so short as yours. It is perfectly fine to give several alternatives in one answer.